# How do I find efficiently, the number of jumps it will take for an element to jump out of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arr

I am trying to write an efficient algorithm that will find the number of jumps it will take for a pawn to exit an array. Lets say we are given an array, for each element in the array if array[k] = n then array[k] is equal to array[k + n];

For example, we have this array [2,3,-1,1,3].

Initially the pawn is at array[0], on first jump it moves from array[0] to array[2] because 0 + array[0] is equal to 2. on the second jump, the pawn moves from A[2] to A[1] because 2 + A[2] = 1; on the third jump, the pawn moves from A[1] to A[4] because 1 + A[1] = 4;
on the fourth jump, the pawn jumps out of the array. It returns 4 for this test case.

If the pawn cant jump out of the array we return -1;

Below is the algorithm I wrote for this problem and it works for a few test cases but fails large test cases. How can I make this algorithm more efficient.

```
function jumpOut(A) { 
  let start = 0;
  let end = A.length - 1
  let pawn = 0;
  
  while (start < end){
    pawn= start + A[start]  
    start++;
  }
  
  if(pawn === end){
    return pawn
  }
  
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: What exactly does "it fails" mean? Does *anything* happen? Are errors reported?

Comment: Also isn't it possible that `pawn` can be greater than `end`, and not equal to it?

Comment: what a fascinating problem! my instinct tells me you cannot do better than O(n)

Comment: @Pointy if you put a greater or equal to end returns the correct answer for a few test cases. Just throws an error. I am not even allowed to see the test case but apparently the pawn can jump in two directions and where theres very large forward and backward steps, it fails.

Comment: Well you're not checking for `pawn < 0` either.

Comment: @Pointy I didnt even think about that. It could jump extreme backward on some cases.

Comment: What happens in your code if the array is `[1, -1, 5]` ?  (The directions would be to return `-1`, I believe.)

Comment: @ScottSauyet sorry it returns -1. It cant jump

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the number of moves required to get out of the array can be done in a linear time if the pawn always jumps EXACTLY the amount specified in the given array.

Before each jump, you can check if the current position of the pawn has been previously visited. If yes, that means there exists a loop that the pawn cannot get out of so return -1. Otherwise keep jumping and return the final count.

```
function getNumRequiredMoves(jumps) {
  // Remember the positions that have been visited
  let isVisited = Array(jumps.length).fill(false);
  // Position of the pawn
  let position = 0;
  // Final result
  let numMoves = 0;

  while (position >= 0 && position < jumps.length) {
    if (isVisited[position]) {
      // This position has been visited before
      return -1;
    }
    // Mark this position as visited
    isVisited[position] = true;
    // Jump
    position += jumps[position];
    // Increment the jump counter
    ++numMoves;
  }

  return numMoves;
}
```

Now at a given time if the pawn can jump anywhere between `[1, jumps[position]]`, you can use dynamic programming to efficiently find the number of required moves.

Comment: Thanks. I absolutely forgot about using an array to check for jumped elements.

Comment: does this solution account for jumping out of the array from the start (left direction) as well?